# PHP Ajax passing two values - 1 dropdown menu 2 buttons

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

i have got following code working well for dropdown menu but as you can see second value (next_val=250f3) is static. i want to make is dynamic should change on click.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

 function showUser(str)
 {
     if (str == "")
     {
         document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
         return;
     }
     if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
     {
         xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
     }
     else
     {
         xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
     }
     xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function()
     {
         if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200)
         {
             document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
         }
     }
     xmlhttp.open("GET", "productlistajax.php?q=" + str + "&next_val=250f3", true);
     xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
```

here is the drop down menu code.

```
 <select id="maxDaysSinceAdded" name="shorting" onchange="showUser(this.value)">
     <option selected='selected' value="1">Most Recent</option>
     <option value="2">Lowest Price</option>
     <option value="3">Highst Price</option>
 </select>
```

how to use button to pass value live above drop down menu

```
<button type="button" name="buttonpassvalue" onclick="">Value</button>
```

thanks

Comment: I don't understand what you value you want to put in next_val.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `showUser()` on the change event of `select tag`. So in this case, you will have to read the value from the script itself before sending the ajax request.

You can modify your code as

```
var buttonValue = document.getElementsByName('buttonpassvalue').item(0).value;
xmlhttp.open("GET", "productlistajax.php?q=" + str + "&next_val=" + buttonValue, true);
```

Comment: thanks karan....can we call separate value of function showUser(str,strsecond)....something like showUser(str.this.value) and then second showUser(strsecond.this.value)

Comment: You can pass two arguments to the function.. but, I don't really get what are you trying to say? Please elaborate!!!